# SQL: select, sort and join tables

Tags: sql

For example I have table 'orders' with columns: ID, order_date, order_price. I need to sort part of table with previous dates by DESC and part of table for future dates by ASC.
For previous it would be:

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_date < CURRENT_DATE() ORDER BY DESC
```

For future dates it would be:

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_date >= CURRENT_DATE() ORDER BY ASC
```

How can I combine these requests in one?

Comment: `UNION` clause?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Can order_date be null?

Answer (score 0):

assuming mysql 8 or  later then row_number window function
(based on (current_date() is a mysql function)

```
select results.* from (
SELECT 0 - row_number() over (order by order_date desc) as RowNum 
     , * FROM orders WHERE order_date < CURRENT_DATE() 
union
SELECT row_number() over (order by order_date asc) as RowNum
     , * FROM orders WHERE order_date >= CURRENT_DATE() 
) results
order by results.RowNum asc
```

Might need a tweek on the orders before current date

Answer (score 0):

Since the DBMS wasn't provided just assuming it supports some DATEDIFF function. I'm sure there's a way to handle this in one clause, but can't think of it.

```
 ORDER
    BY CASE WHEN current_date < order_date THEN 0
            ELSE 1
        END,
       CASE WHEN current_date >= order_date THEN DATEDIFF('day',current_date,order_date)
            ELSE DATEDIFF('day',current_date,order_date)*-1
        END
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
order by (case when order_date < current_date() then 1 else 2 end),
         (case when order_date < current_date() then order_date end) desc,
         order_date asc
```

The first key explicitly puts the older records first.  The second explicitly orders them by descending date.  And the third orders the rest ascendingly.